# PHP Loops random number

Tags: php

I want to make a randomly number(8 digits)...
Like..

1. The random 8 digit number is 0896 62479872
2. The random 8 digit number is 0896 80400616
3. The random 8 digit number is 0896 32287359
4. The random 8 digit number is 0896 43138996
5. The random 8 digit number is 0896 16297413

repeatedly until I got 1000 different numbers

Here's my code :

```
<?php

$digits_needed=8;

$random_number=''; // set up a blank string

$count=0;

while ( $count < $digits_needed ) {
    $random_digit = mt_rand(0, 9);

    $random_number .= $random_digit;
    $count++;
}

echo "The random $digits_needed digit number is 0896$random_number<br>";

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get 1000 8 digit numbers like this

```
 $count = 1000;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i ++) {
        $random_digit = mt_rand(0, 99999999);

        echo "The random 8 digit number is 0896 $random_digit<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
function randStrGenDigit($len){
    $result = "";
    $chars = "0123456789";
    $charArray = str_split($chars);
    for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
        $randItem = array_rand($charArray);
        $result .= "".$charArray[$randItem];
    }
    return $result;
}
$digits_needed=8;

$random_number=''; // set up a blank string

$count=0;

for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++) {
  echo "The random ".$digits_needed." digit number is 0896 ".$randStrGenDigit($digits_needed)."<br>";
}
```